# Delete User in /etc/group

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, tor

i have tor install on my raspberry.

```
*:/home/bitcoin $ cat /etc/group | grep debian-tor
debian-tor:x:116:bitcoin,root,pi
```

over can i add a user

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-tor bitcoin
```

but how can i delete?

i wan't root and pi delete.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Do you want to remove `root` and `pi` from the group `debian-tor`? Or are you trying to remove some users from your system?

Comment: Thanks. Yes i want to remove root and pi from the group: debian-tor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gpasswd` instead.

```
gpasswd -d user group
```

It also has option for adding user to group

```
gpasswd -a user group
```

Comment: Thanks, with -d i have the user deleted. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `usermod -G` (note: without `-a`) for each of those users with a list of the groups s/he must stay member of. `man usermod`:

> ```
>    -G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]          
>
>        If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user will be removed from the group.
> ```